# How to use Cauchy sequence on $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \le q|a_{n+1}-a_n|$

Tags: calculus

I want to apply Cauchy prinicpal on the following question:

If exists constant $$0<q<1$$
such that $$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \le q|a_{n+1}-a_n|$$
for any $n$ then $a_n$ converges.

Now if I just think about it what I see is that as $n$ goes up the distance between his members becoming smaller and smaller since even if i take the last 2 elements and multiple them by a small number ($<1$) the distance is still smaller.

My conclusion is that the sequence will probably converge because of that, but my method is not math is just some logic which may be wrong.

I feel like Cauchy can help me here but I have no idea how to apply it

Comment: Hint: $|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \le q^n|a_1-a_0|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $m > n$, we have

$$|a_m - a_n| = |(a_m - a_{m-1}) + (a_{m-1} - a_{m-2}) + \ldots + (a_{n+1} - a_n)|$$

$$|a_m - a_n| \leq |a_m - a_{m-1}| + |a_{m-1} - a_{m-2}| + \ldots + |a_{n+1} - a_n|$$

$$|a_m - a_n| \leq (1 + q + q^2 + \ldots + q^{m-n-1}) |a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq \frac{q^n}{1-q}|a_{1} - a_0|$$

Comment: Thanks can you explain to me why & how you open the right side in your first line to this sum? and the third line how did you insert the q?

Comment: It is just adding some terms in between and deleting them simultaneously. For example looking at $a_{m-1}$. I want to do this because I can use triangle inequality in the second line and eventually get a geometric series, which I get a hint from the fact that $q < 1$. In fact this is a very useful and common technique in dealing with Cauchy sequence. FYI you may look at Banach fixed point theorem.